# Custom back bar item button

Tags: ios, swift

Rather than going back 1 view controller, I am attempting to pop back to the first view controller under the navigation controller.

```
func setupBackBarButtons() {

    let myBackButton = UIButton()
    myBackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentListController), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    let myCustomBackButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myBackButton)

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem  = myCustomBackButtonItem // This works
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = myCustomBackButtonItem // This doesn't.

}

func presentListController() {
    navigationController?.popToViewController((self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0])!, animated: true)
}
```

I'm slightly confused to why I can add the custom button to the `leftBarButtonItem` but not the `backBarButtonItem`.

I only want to add a target to pop it back to the first view controller but not change the title (Still keep it as back with the `<` in the in corner).  I would do this with the `leftBarButtonItem` but I'm not to sure how to keep the `<` in the title.

Comment: you can add a image (<) for self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem know ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the functionality of the back button. When you try to do that, you just break the back button. You can customize the back button's appearance but you cannot change its action. You must provide a nil action and target so that the back button will still work as a back button.

To customize the back button's *behavior*, change the behavior of the navigation controller itself. Give the navigation controller a delegate and implement `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`. In your implementation, look to see how we got here. If we got here because we popped to it, pop further (to the root).

Comment: When you say 'break the back button', Is this actually a bad thing? I this case, I'd say I don't need the back button.  Not sure what you mean by 'Give the navigation controller a delegate and implement navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:' neither.  Is it obj-c?

Comment: "In this case, I'd say I don't need the back button" Sure, then don't use it. _You_ were the one who said you needed the back button (that is what the back-pointing chevron symbol is). You said "(Still keep it as back with the `<` in the in corner)". That's the back button.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was I don't need what the back button  does (pop back 1 view controller). Nevertheless, I want the back button to be displayed and pop back to the root view controller, rather than just 1 vc. I guess what I'm asking for is a custom bar button item to also display the back-pointing chevron symbol. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, if you want a chevron image, make a chevron image. But the _built-in_ chevron image is part of the back button. "I want the back button to be displayed and pop back to the root view controller" And I told you how to do that.